# A program to edit html/css website?

Tags: html, css, web

I'm looking to edit a simple html/css template into something that I want. 
My only problem is that I'm not good enough with html/css to be able to layout everything fine regardless of the screen size and browser.

So I was wondering what is a good program which can help he edit this html.

I was thinking something that kind of takes the html and css as input and I can just delete certain elements or add things and it automatically creates the correct html for it.

Any Suggestions?

(I don't mind if its paid or free)

Comment: Upvoted and voted to close :p

Comment: Am I crazy or does this question have 2 upvotes?

Comment: @fotanus What's the upvote for?

Comment: It is actually a good question. Just doesn't fit the site.

Comment: Ramis, I'd say no - in the long run. If you get your hands on Dreamweaver and start messing with your template, you'll realize quickly that 'the best money can buy' will be no substitute for 'getting good enough' expertise and knowledge to solve your puzzle. I think it's a legit, beginner's question and assumption. In the long run it's better for the reckoning to come sooner rather than later.

Comment: oopps sorry for the wrong site and its not meant to be used in the long run. Just this once really.

Comment: Shouldn't this question be more appropriate for [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions)?

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver is good. 
You could also use Firebug in Firefox and see what the html does and delete the html from a simple html editor program.